# windows 10 upgrade from IIS6

Tags: iis-6, windows-10

hi dear community,
 is there any way to upgrade to newer versions of IIS on windows 10 ?

I am trying to install some crm for testing purposes, but its components need IIS version 7 or newer

here's the error message I get:

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/awxxl.png"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS 10 is included with Windows 10, you just have to install it first. Here's how to : http://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/ (it is the same procedure on Windows 8 and 10)

Comment: :D I got IIS6 preinstalled somehow http://i.imgur.com/d9nDsF3.png

Comment: This is just the IIS 6 management compatibility component, if you don't need  it you can uncheck this box to uninstall it. The rest of the components are part of IIS 10. If you start IIS Manager, and click About IIS in the Help menu, you should see that it's version 10.